# How are "word boundaries" identified in Python sklearn CountVectorizer's analyzer parameter?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, countvectorizer

Python sklearn CountVectorizer has an "analyzer" parameter which has a "char_wb" option. According to the definition,

```
"Option ‘char_wb’ creates character n-grams only from text inside word boundaries; n-grams at the edges of words are padded with space.".
```

My question here is, how does CountVectorizer identify a "word" from a string? More specifically, are "words" simply space-separated strings from a sentence, or are they identified by more complex techniques like word_tokenize from nltk?

The reason I ask this is that I am analyzing social media data which has a whole lot of @mentions and #hashtags. Now, nltk's word_tokenize breaks up a "@mention" into ["@", "mention], and a "#hashtag" into ["#", "hashtag"]. If I feed these into CountVectorizer with ngram_range > 1, the "#" and "@" will never be captured as features. Moreover, I want character n-grams (with char_wb) to capture "@m" and "#h" as features, which won't ever happen if CountVectorizer breaks up @mentions and #hashtags into ["@","mentions"] and ["#","hashtags"].

What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seperates words by whitespace as you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/1495f6924/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py#L688).

```
def _char_wb_ngrams(self, text_document):
    """Whitespace sensitive char-n-gram tokenization.
    Tokenize text_document into a sequence of character n-grams
    operating only inside word boundaries. n-grams at the edges
    of words are padded with space."""
    # normalize white spaces
    text_document = self._white_spaces.sub(" ", text_document)

    min_n, max_n = self.ngram_range
    ngrams = []

    # bind method outside of loop to reduce overhead
    ngrams_append = ngrams.append


    for w in text_document.split():
        w = ' ' + w + ' '
        w_len = len(w)
        for n in range(min_n, max_n + 1):
            offset = 0
            ngrams_append(w[offset:offset + n])
            while offset + n < w_len:
                offset += 1
                ngrams_append(w[offset:offset + n])
            if offset == 0:   # count a short word (w_len < n) only once
                break
    return ngrams
```

text_document.split() splits by whitespace.

Comment: Ah. I see... Thanks!